# Jquery cloned element is replacing himself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

I have been getting some issue with cloning element, when I am cloning an element and add it to the DOM it work perfectly but when I am trying to clone a second one its replacing the first added clone, do you know where it could come from ?

```
  var clone_count = 1;
  var add_row = $('.modeloRowBlock-hidden').clone(true) // clone my div that is hidden
  $('.add-modelo-block').on('click', function() { // binded button to add my div
    var current_row = add_row.removeClass('modeloRowBlock-hidden hidden').addClass('modeloRowBlock' + ' ' + clone_count++) ;
    $('.modeloRowBlock-hidden').before(current_row);
  });
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help :).

Jonathan.

EDIT : My bad I made it work, actually cloned that way for another reason, and re integrated it in the .on and it worked.

Comment: You are inserting the cloned element `.before()` the original element?

Comment: Yes exactly I am inserting it before.

Comment: What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You clone your row only once.
If you're using before on a single element, it will move the elements.

> If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location
>   elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved before the target (not cloned):

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/before/